# Get max value from nested dictionary return both keys if equal

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have following dictionary

```
  {
    "match_1":{
        "home_team":2,
        "away_team":1
    },
    "match_2":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":2
    },
    "match_3":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":4}


}
```

I want to sum home team and away team goals and find which team won in aggregate
if both have same score result is draw.
I tried converting to `tuple` and used `max` with `lambda` but it fails when result score is same.

required output for current question: `winner! away team`

if same goals in all matches in aggregate: `Draw`

Comment: _"I tried ..."_: the best way to describe what you tried is to actually show it, as a [mre]. This is really as simple as iterating over the values of your dictionary (each value is a dictionary itself) and summing the appropriate keys of these dictionaries. You shouldn't need any conversions to tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tricky way

```
d={
    "match_1":{
        "home_team":2,
        "away_team":1
    },
    "match_2":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":2
    },
    "match_3":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":4}


}
score = ((i["home_team"], i["away_team"]) for i in d.values())
t1,t2 = map(sum,zip(*score))
[["Away team","Home team"][t1>t2], "Draw"][t1==t2]
```

Comment: This works only for the specific sample input, where the `home_team` key happens to come before the `away_team` key in each sub-dict. One should never assume the order of keys in a dict unless specifically guaranteed.

Comment: @blhsing Now it will work

Comment: You should also explain your "tricky way", because it (at least the last line) is not very readable. I doubt that list and boolean indexing is more efficient than a simple `if..elif..else`, which is much more readable.

Comment: Also, if `d` is large, one way to gain efficiency is by making `score` a generator instead of a list, so that `d.values()` is only iterated over once.

Comment: Yes, I created `score` as generator. It will be more efficient.

Comment: I did some experimentation, and found that your tricky way of selecting strings is in fact _slower_ than the more readable way. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8p6c.png, which shows the mean of 25 function calls for functions that return the required string using one of three methods: your "tricky" approach, and plain old `if..elif..else` and two ternary statements. The code used to generate this plot is here: https://pastebin.com/sht7LKJ4 The `if..elif..else` and two ternary statement approach is about 2x faster than the "tricky" one. Conclusion: tricky one-liners aren't always useful

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i agree with your results but I never said that this one liner approach is fast, this is just another way of representing if elif else that i have studied on some online resource. I feel one should try some innovative things to learn new things. Can you try the above one liner with tuple, that will be fast for sure.

Comment: Right... My point is it's a bad way of doing the same thing because it's worse in terms of speed and readability. Just because you _can_ condense something down to one line doesn't mean you _should_, and a lot of tutorials suffer from the misconception that fewer lines are better, which leads them to popularize convoluted but pointless one-liners like this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249238/discussion-between-deepak-tripathi-and-pranav-hosangadi).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below approach

```
table =   {
    "match_1":{
        "home_team":2,
        "away_team":1
    },
    "match_2":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":2
    },
    "match_3":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":4}


}
score = {}
for match in table.keys():
    for team in table[match].keys():
        if team in score.keys():
            score[team]+=table[match][team]
        else:
            score[team]=table[match][team]

if score["home_team"]==score["away_team"]:
    print("Draw")
elif score["home_team"]>score["away_team"]:
    print("Winner! Home team")
else:
    print("Winner! Away team")
```

Output

```
> python -u "run.py"
Winner! Away team
>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to do this, and one of the ways is to use `reduce` function

```
import functools

d = {
    "match_1": {"home_team": 2, "away_team": 1},
    "match_2": {"home_team": 1, "away_team": 2},
    "match_3": {"home_team": 1, "away_team": 4},
}

result = functools.reduce(
    lambda a, b: {
        "home_team": a["home_team"] + b["home_team"],
        "away_team": a["away_team"] + b["away_team"],
    },
    d.values(),
)

if result["home_team"] > result["away_team"]:
    print("winner! home_team")
elif result["away_team"] > result["home_team"]:
    print("winner! away_team")
else:
    print("Draw")
```

Answer (score 1):

I provide an intuition way to deal this problem. You can try the following code snippet:

```
match =   {
    "match_1":{
        "home_team":2,
        "away_team":1
    },
    "match_2":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":2
    },
    "match_3":{
        "home_team":1,
        "away_team":4}
}

home_team_score = 0
away_team_score = 0

for m in match:
    home_team_score += match[m]['home_team']
    away_team_score += match[m]['away_team']

if home_team_score > away_team_score:
    print("winner! home team")
elif home_team_score < away_team_score: 
    print("winner! away team")
else:
    print("Draw")
```